# Pod versions are causing CFBundleShortVersionString errors

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to upload version 1.0.0 of an app to iTunes Connect. CFBundleShortVersionString is set to 1.0.0.

After archiving, validating, and attempting to upload to iTunes Connect, I always get errors like this:

[image]

I noticed that those CFBundleShortVersionString values come from my pods:

[image]
[image]

What's going on? How can I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Open your *info.plist file of SVProgressHUD* (not the info.plist of whole app)in Pods and change the Bundle version string,short from 'HEAD on 1.1.3' to '1.1.3'.